# Bitwise operation without using any predefined C functions

Tags: c, algorithm

I need to write a program in C to solve the following problem but the catch is that i cannot use loops, conditions, or any predefined C functions

> You are given three numbers a∣b, a∣c, and b∣c, where ∣ represents the logical operator or. For example, 3∣5=011∣101=111=7. You will be prompted to print the three numbers a, b and c in the output.

Obviously, this issue does not necessarily have a unique answer and you only need to output one of the valid answers.

Example:

```
input: 5 7 7
output: 1 4 7
```

I tried to turn the decimal input numbers into binary but couldn't do it without using a loop.

Comment: So how are you getting on with it? We won't write the code for you. Show us what you've managed so far.

Comment: Print...without using any "predefined C functions". Sure, that sounds totally reasonable.

Comment: _"here_ `∣` _represents the logical operator or"_ - You mean the **binary** OR operator, right?

Comment: *You are given three numbers...*  "Given" how, exactly?  Command-line parameters?  Contents of a file? (If so, how would the file be specified?)  Input to be read from `stdin`?  Morse code from a carrier pigeon pecking on your monitor?

Comment: Good luck reading the numbers without using loops and conditions or predefined functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this problem one bit at a time. Define `d = a | b`, `e = a | c`, `f = b | c`.

- If all three of {`d`, `e`, `f`} are 0, then we know {`a`, `b`, `c`} are all 0 too.
- If exactly two of {`d`, `e`, `f`} are 0, that is impossible because each variable {`a`, `b`, `c`} will force two of {`d`, `e`, `f`} to be 1.
- If exactly one of {`d`, `e`, `f`} is 0, then exactly one of {`a`, `b`, `c`} is 1, and the rest are 0.
- If exactly none of {`d`, `e`, `f`} are 0, then it's ambiguous at any two or three of {`a`, `b`, `c`} can be 1.

It suffices to solve: `a = d & e`, `b = d & f`, `c = e & f`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int a,b,c;
scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
printf("%d %d %d", a&b, a&c, b&c);
return 0;}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?